# Oracle DB connection with c# failed

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've installed Oracle DB on another pc(A) and trying to establish the connection from my pc(B). Now when I'm trying to debug the application I get this error- "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (ParseConnectParams()).]Invalid connection."

```
    public void InsertionTest()

    {            
        string cmdText = @"Insert into O_TEST_TABLE (ID,Name,MOBILE) Values (4, 'rD','798984');";
        string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HR"].ConnectionString;

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))// "Provider=SQLOLEDB; DATA SOURCE=172.16.1.220:1521/orcl;PASSWORD=hr;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=hr"))
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
        {
            con.Open();

            int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rowsUpdated == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success.");
            }
        }           
    }
```

In my web config file, the connection string is-

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HR" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=HR;DATA SOURCE=172.16.1.13:1521/orcl;PASSWORD=hr;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=hr; OLEDB.NET=True " /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use an MS SQL Server connection string to connect to the Oracle database. Did you look at the examples on [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)?

Answer (score 1):

I feel provider should be `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle`